# stop fixing position of navbar changing alignment

Tags: css, alignment

I am currently creating a navbar with the following bootstrap code:

```
<div class="nav-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a id="logo" class="nav-link" href="#">Lattes <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a class="nav-link right-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link right-link" href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link right-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link right-link" href="#">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link right-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is producing the desired result, with the links to the right and title to the left as such:
[image]

I am attempting to fix the position of the navbar to the top of the screen so that the navbar is always at the top of the users window with the following css:

> ```
>     .navbar {
>         background-color: #222222;
>         border-radius: 5px; 
>         position:fixed;
>     }
> ```

This works in keeping the bar at the top of the screen, however, it ruins the alignment, and left aligns all of the elements in the bar: 
[image]

Is there a solution to fix the navbar to the position without changing the alignment?

Comment: did you try to fix  the "nav-wrap" instead of the navbar ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your .navbar initially had an another position than 'fixed'.

I would to suggest you to add the `position: fixed;` to the 'nav-wrap' element.

Comment: I have, the same issue occurs.

Comment: Could you please provide your full CSS for this navbar so that I can help you ?